# How to assign text symbols in ABAP Screen Painter?

Tags: abap, dynpro

Does anybody know how to display in a screen a text symbol?
It is necessary because of translation.

Comment: I don't get what is difficult in displaying an ABAP variable in a Dynpro: you assign the Text Symbol to the Dynpro variable and that's it. What did you try, what is your issue?

Comment: If I add text-s01 field symbol (for just example) to the text fields name attribute in the screen painter nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

The reason what you are trying to doesnt work is because of how the "Binding" in SAP Screens to Program works.

The screen-vars are bound to Program global variables using the identical names at PBO time.

So just set the global from the text-elements pool variable :

data gs_xyz type zbla.
gs_xyz-my_field = text-001.   "set screen variable from text elements

And place gs_xyz-my_field on the dynrpo.

Now it will work.